# Does SignalR support the Publish/Subscribe messaging paradigm?

Tags: messaging, publish-subscribe, signalr

I want to use pub-sub messaging between multiple servers in a web farm to maintain their local (ASP.NET) caches in sync.

Could this be easily done with SignalR?

If it is possible, how can I do so?

Comment: Would it not be more appropriate to use a distributed cache suche as Appfabric or Ncache rather than roll your own?

Comment: Hi Steve, we're planning to use a distributed cache. In any case, and due to some specific performance requirements, for some parts of our application it is really important to have a local cache. Thanks

Comment: Hi Carlos. I get that but doesn't a distributed cache maintain local copies of cached content? If you run the dCache on your web servers rather than separately then the cache architecture should take care of keeping them in sync so you get the benefit of a local cache with synchronisation.

Comment: I understand what you say and I'm aware of the local caching features of AppFabric. Yet Appfabric gets really expensive when you need to use clusters (it requires Windows Enterprise). And a local cache is orders of magnitude faster than a distributed cache (there's no network, serialization-deserialization), etc

Comment: You can use Signalr this way. In fact this is how we're implementing peer to peer scale out. Each node in the farm has a local cache and each an endpoint to ping when data comes in. Once all nodes discover each other (this will be pluggable), messages that come into any one node will notify all other nodes in the farm and populate their local caches.

Comment: @dfowler, is there any code available that would help me getting started? I never used SignalR before. Thanks

Comment: @dfowler , what's the current status of the peer to peer scale out? I saw that there are some branches with some code for scaling out but they seem to be outdated. Could you let me know where should I should look?