# Architecture For A Real-Time Data Feed And Website

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, comet

I have been given access to a real time data feed which provides location information, and I would like to build a website around this, but I am a little unsure on what architecture to use to achieve my needs.

Unfortunately the feed I have access to will only allow a single connection per IP address, therefore building a website that talks directly to the feed is out - as each user would generate a new request, which would be rejected. It would also be desirable to perform some pre-processing on the data, so I guess I will need some kind of back end which retrieves the data, processes it, then makes it available to a website.

From a front end connection perspective, web services sounds like it may work, but would this also create multiple connections to the feed for each user? I would also like the back end connection to be persistent, so that data is retrieved and processed even when the site is not being visited, I believe IIS will recycle web services and websites when they are idle?

I would like to keep the design fairly flexible - in future I will be adding some mobile clients, so the API needs to support remote connections.

The simple solution would have been to log all the processed data to a database, which could then be picked up by the website, but this loses the real-time aspect of the data. Ideally I would be looking to push the data to the website every time the data changes or now data is received.

What is the best way of achieving this, and what technologies are there out there that may assist here? Comet architecture sounds close to what I need, but that would require building a back end that can handle multiple web based queries at once, which seems like quite a task.

Ideally I would be looking for a C# / ASP.NET based solution with Javascript client side, although I guess this question is more based on architecture and concepts than technological implementations of these.

Thanks in advance for all advice!

Answer (score 2):

### Realtime Data Consumer

The simplest solution would seem to be having one component that is dedicated to reading the realtime feed. It could then publish the received data on to a queue (or multiple queues) for consumption by other components within your architecture.

This component **(A)** would be a standalone process, maybe a service.

### Queue consumers

The queue(s) can be read by:

1. a component **(B)** dedicated to persisting data for future retrieval or querying. If the amount of data is large you could add more components that read from the persistence queue.
2. a component **(C)** that publishes the data directly to any connected subscribers. It could also do some processing, but if you are looking at doing large amounts of processing you may need multiple components that perform this task.

### Realtime web technology components (D)

If you are using a .NET stack then it seems like [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/) is getting the most traction. You could also look at [XSockets](http://xsockets.net) (there are more options in my [realtime web tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide). Just search for '.NET'.

You'll want to use signalR to manage subscriptions and then to publish messages to registered client (PubSub - [this SO post seems relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449601/does-signalr-support-the-publish-subscribe-messaging-paradigm), maybe you can ask for a bit more info).

You could also look at offloading the PubSub component to a hosted service such as [Pusher](http://pusher.com), *who I work for*. This will handle managing subscriptions and component C would just need to publish data to an appropriate channel. There are other options all listed in the [realtime web tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide).

All these components come with a JavaScript library.

### Summary

Components:

- **A** - .NET service - that publishes info to queue(s)
- **Queues** - MSMQ, NServiceBus etc.
- **B** - Could also be a simple .NET service that reads a queue.
- **C** - this really depends on D since some realtime web technologies will be able to directly integrate. But it could also just be a simple .NET service that reads a queue.
- **D** - Realtime web technology that offers a simple way of routing information to subscribers (PubSub).

If you provide any more info I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution to this would be something like http://rubyeventmachine.com/ or http://nodejs.org/ . It's not asp.net, but it can easily solve the issue of distributing real time data to other users. Since user connections, subscriptions and broadcasting to channels are built in to each, that will make coding the rest super simple. Your clients would just connect over standard tcp.

If you needed clients to poll for updates then you would need a que system to store info for the next request. That could be a simple array, or a more complicated que system depending on your requirements and number of users.

There may be solutions for .net that I am not aware of that do the same thing, but those are the 2 I  know of.